# setNumStars() not working in android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, ratingbar

I have to dynamically create rating bar in which the the number of stars to be set is passed from the server. Here i'm getting the value of number of stars to be set and its assigned to `setNumStars()` method. My code and the design generated are shown below.
Here i'm getting n number of stars.Thanks in advance.   `

```
 if(FO.answerType[i].equals("S")){          
    TextView quest = new TextView(this);

     quest.setText(FO.question[i]);
     quest.setTextSize(textsize);
     quest.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);                  
     quest.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
     quest.setPadding(10, 6, 10, 6);
     quest.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
     lila.addView(quest);

     RatingBar rate = new RatingBar(this);                  
     rate.setNumStars(Integer.parseInt(FO.nos[i]));     

     lila.addView(rate); 


        }`
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep the `Layout Params` as `WRAP_CONTENT`. It will do the trick, like

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        RatingBar rate = new RatingBar(this);
        rate.setRating(2);
        rate.setNumStars(4);
        rate.setProgress(1);
        rate.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        frameLayout.addView(rate);
```

Output : 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try .setRating(float value) and here your have a related question: [Set value in RatingBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750823/set-value-in-ratingbar)

There you have the correct implementation of a RatingBar and the setRating method.

Answer (score 1):

Just RatingBar should be placed in the layout, which has a property wrap_content.
Magic does not exist. Check that returns:

> Integer.parseInt(FO.nos[i])

Suddenly there is 0.
[See it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23282712/android-using-setnumstars-to-change-stars-during-execution-make-the-ratings-act) so.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
rate.setRating(Float.valueOf(FO.nos[i]));
```

**Edit for Dynamic Seekbar :**

```
public class MovieAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    List<PostVO> movieList;

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        LinearLayout ll;
        RatingBar rb;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            ll = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll);
            rb = new RatingBar(context);
            rb.setNumStars(10);
            rb.setStepSize(1);
            ll.addView(rb);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Snackbar.make(v, movieList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getTitle(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public MovieAdapter(Context context,List<PostVO> movieList)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.movieList = movieList;
    }

    @Override
    public MovieAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_movie_list, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MovieAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.rb.setRating(Float.valueOf(movieList.get(i).getRating()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(movieList != null && !movieList.isEmpty())
        {
            return movieList.size();
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry boss this too has no effect. The output is still d same.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(FO.nos[i])` retuns value 5. The code is working when i'm not dynamically creating the design and passing value to set the number of stars.

Comment: I'm not having an xml for this layout, I have just created a linear layout and was creating the design dynamically.

Comment: @SunilGeorgeJacob then you need to set properties dynamically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89026/discussion-between-sunil-george-jacob-and-sanat-shukla).

Answer (score 0):

**You need to put following code for this-**

RatingBar ratingBar = new RatingBar(this);
ratingBar.setRating(5);